# using browser-sync with django on docker-compose

Tags: django, docker-compose, browser-sync

I'm doing a project for college and I've never used docker before, I usually use browser-sync when working on static files, but now when I'm using Django on docker-compose (i followed [THIS](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) tutorial ), I have no idea how to set it up to work, can anybody give me advice or direct me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i found a solution,
Start by following the tutorial [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) to set up django with docker-compose, by the end of this you should have a working base django project. then follow the steps below.

**How to Use "livereload" With "docker-compose" :**

on you host machine, open the command line or the terminal and do :

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install django-livereload-server
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

> PS: i'm using psycopg2 in docker-compose that's why i'm installing it,
>   if you're using something else, install it instead of psycopg2

Now add to the requirements.txt file (from the tutorial) this line

```
 django-livereload-server
```

The file should look like this (if you followed the tutorial step by step, you can change according to what db you want to use)

```
 Django==2.0
 psycopg2-binary
 django-livereload-server
```

Open the terminal, cd to your projects directory, and do:

```
docker-compose build
```

to download the new django-livereload to your docker environment.
Now, you've everything installed,
you need to setup your project to use the django-livereload-server  module, 
In your project's settings.py 
add livereload to INSTALLED_APPS:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'livereload',
    ...
]
```

and add the livereload middleware to MIDDLEWARE:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'livereload.middleware.LiveReloadScript',
]
```

and make sure that DEBUG is set to True.

now you can start developing,
open 2 consoles (terminals) in your project's directory

in the first one do :

```
python manage.py livereload
```

wait until the server starts, when it's working, leave it running, and in the second terminal do:

```
docker-compose up
```

the server in the second terminal is running the django development server, and the server in the first terminal is feeding the first one a livereload.js file, which is used by the django-livereload-server module to inject css, automatically reload html and js when saving, .. etc

> PS : make sure the first server (livereload) is working before you launch the second one

i hope this helped !

Comment: This looks good! Will test this in a tailwindcss project